# Evaluate the sum $x + \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{x^5}{5} + ... $

Tags: calculus, integration, summation

> Evaluate the sum $$x + \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{x^5}{5} + ... $$

I was able to notice that:  $$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n-1}}{2n-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int x^{2n-2}dx = \lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=0}^N \int x^{2n-2} dx  $$

Where should I take it from here? (assuming I'm not the right way)

**EDIT**
Following the anwer:

$$\int \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{2n-1} dx = \int \frac{\sum_{n=0}^\infty (x^2)^n}{x} dx = \int \frac{\frac{1}{1-x^2}}{x} dx= \int \frac{1}{x(1-x^2)}dx = \int \frac{1-x^2+x^2}{x(1-x^2)} = \int \frac{1}{x} dx + \int \frac{x}{1-x^2}dx = \ln(x) + \int \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1-t}dt + C = \ln(x) - \frac{\ln(x^2)}{2} + C$$

1. Is that right?
2. How to evaluate $C$?

Comment: arctanh $x$ around $x=0$ ...

Comment: I'd rather not to use that, since I wish to practice this kind of evaluations.

Comment: Your $\dfrac{\ln(x^2)}{2}$ should be $\dfrac{\ln(1-x^2)}{2}$, I think. But then the answer blows up at $x=0$, which I can't explain.

Comment: in your answer we should have $n>0$ not $n\geq 0$, does this make a change?

Comment: Mathematical mysticism says that since the corresponding series with alternating signs is the inverse tangent, this should be the inverse hyperbolic tangent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got the index wrong. The actual sum is

$$ \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1} = \int \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} x^{2n} \,dx = \int \frac{1}{1-x^2}\,dx $$

This sum converges for $|x| < 1$ and the integral evaluates to

$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{2}\, \ln \left| \frac{1+x}{1-x} \right| + C $$

The constant $C$ can be found by looking at the series expansion (what's $f(0)$?)

Comment: I think you missed the constants $1/2$ when doing partial fraction expansion. You should multiply your answer by $1/2$, which is equivalent to taking the square root of the term inside the logarithm.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Thanks for pointing that out. I did it in my head.

Answer (score 7):

Consider,

$$\sum_{n\ge 1} x^{n-1} = \frac{1}{1-x}$$

Let $x \rightarrow x^2$ and then integrate.

Answer (score 5):

$$\log(1+x) = x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{x^4}{4} + \cdots \\
\log \frac{1}{1-x} = x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} +\frac{x^4}{4} + \cdots $$
and so 
$$\frac{1}{2}(\, \log(1+x) + \log \frac{1}{1-x}\,) = x + \frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}+ \cdots$$
or
$$ x + \frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}+ \cdots= \log \sqrt{ \frac{1+x}{1-x}}$$
for $|x| \le 1$, $x \ne \pm 1$.

$\tiny{\log \sqrt{ \frac{1+x}{1-x}}= \text{arctanh} x= \frac{\arctan(ix)}{i}}$

Comment: That's a very nice approach. Thanks

Comment: No worries. For $0<x<1$, $\frac{1}{1-x}$ is somehow larger than $(1+x)$, as the $\log$s show. Taking $\log{\frac{1}{1-x}}$ is cleaner because all the coefficients of the power series are positive.

Answer (score 1):

Use only your first identity. You should check where the series is absolutelly convergent. In that interval you can change the integral with the sum. That will lead to a known series you shall be able to evaluate. (If you can't solve with the hint I edit this answer later).

Comment: So far that's what I did: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{2n-1} = \frac{\sum_{n=0}^\infty (x^2)^n}{x^2} = \frac{1/(1-x^2)}{x^2} = \frac{1}{x^2(1-x^2)}$

Comment: So we have $\int \frac{1}{x^2(1-x^2)}dx = \int \frac{1}{t(1-t)}dt = \int \frac{1}{t}dt + \int \frac{1}{1-t}dt = \ln(x^2) - \ln(1-x^2) + C$

Comment: Now, if I wanted to evaluate the summation for concrete $x$, what $C$ would be?

Comment: What do you get if you set $x = 0$?  This kind of checking of special values is useful for quickly detecting mistakes.

Comment: Oops.. I should have divide by $x$, not by $x^2$.

Comment: The C depends on the limits of integration. Your integral function is never indefinite to be a function. If you are taking $\int_0^x$ it is one thing, if it is $\int_1^x$ it is another one.